# strange characters are being added to the end of my spf record

Tags: windows, dns, spf

I'm running into a problem I'm a bit new to DNS and couldn't find a solution on the internet.

I'm updating my SPF record with DNS Manager on Windows.

I enter my DNS as below

[image]

But on a platform where I will check any DNS such as mxtoolbox.com, dnschecker.org, I get the following output. It's adding characters to the end of my SPF record.

[image]

[image]

I tried a clean copy. I just tried entering the SPF record. But I couldn't find a solution why it adds the characters there. Is there anyone who had this problem before and solved it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the dns tag states: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&#160;` is the HTML entity for a non-breaking space. Visually, it looks just like a normal space, but it behaves differently, in ways that are irrelevant and unsupported for DNS. I'm not sure how it got there, but it should just be a regular space, not a non-breaking one. I suggest you edit the record and replace that space with a regular press-the-spacebar space character.

Comment: i tried clean paste many times but strangely this solved the problem :)